# using the "grant options" command i want to assign the exact privileges as one user to another in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, privileges, sql-grant

Not sure if this can be done but from everything I read it seems possible, just not sure how to code it. at best I would imagine it would look something like

```
CREATE USER user1@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'passwd';
GRANT OPTIONS userA
ON test
TO user1
```

and that is where I get lost, how do I tell my schema I want to grant 'user1' the exact privileges as 'userA'. thanks in advance, and I think that I am close or on the right track.
MYSQL workbench 5.2.38 CE

I FOUND THIS

**GRANT PROXY ON 'localuser'@'localhost' TO 'externaluser'@'somehost';

When PROXY is granted, it must be the only privilege named in the GRANT statement, the REQUIRE clause cannot be given, and the only permitted WITH option is WITH GRANT OPTION.

Proxying requires that the proxy user authenticate through a plugin that returns the name of the proxied user to the server when the proxy user connects, and that the proxy user have the PROXY privilege for the proxied user. For details and examples, see Section 6.3.7, “Proxy Users”.

so it can be done, and I have not referred to section 6.3.7 just yet. Once I know more I will post more
**

Comment: thry looking at this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598248/mysql-copy-a-user

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the link but I am afraid that the links on the page are not good anymore, the first comes back with a page not found and the second goes to a MySQL 6.0 download

Answer (score 1):

Ok. If you want, you can just copy the record of user from `mysql` table and eit the user name. Then execute flush privileges.

This works before for me.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I get what your saying, just not how to do it

Comment: Create an insert statement that will insert on the mysql_user table. The execute the flush priviledges.